# 406 Error on UI

Tags: spring-mvc, json.net

I am returning JSON response from spring Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/portal", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
        @ResponseBody
        Object getHomePage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
            return getHome(session);

        }
```

but on UI I am getting 406 error because in the Response Content-Type is coming as text/html

```
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1

Spring version 4.3.16.RELEASE
Gradle Dependencies
    compile "org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13" 
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.5" 
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.5
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`
2. Remove `@RequestBody`

Why you want to return (probably) view as JSON is a mistery to me.